# how can restrict my field should accepts only numbers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using `text_field` and `number_field` for one field. This field changes depends upon the `question_type` selected. The `number_field` is working fine in `chrome`. It accepts only `number` in `chrome` and not in `mozila` and `IE`.

How can I create a method in model or how can i tell that `:answer_no` should be only `numbers`(1, 0.1, or any numbers not integers). It should not accept string.

```
<% if question_type == 'C' %>
  <%= f.text_field :answer_no %>
<% elsif (question_type == 'T') and (question_type == 'F') and (question_type != 'C') and (question_type != 'Y') and (question_type != 'Z') %>
  <%= f.number_field :answer_no %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the Ideas friends. But I made it simple by your ideas.

```
validates :answer_no, numericality: true, :if => :answer_cannot_be_string?


def answer_cannot_be_string?
  not (question_type.in? %w{ C Y Z })
end
```

So, Its accepts the decimal and numbers by the question types. I did from the ideas of your answers. So I put +1 to both of you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple JavaScript function to accept only number in the text field.

Add below JavaScript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
         alert("Please Enter Only Numeric Value:");
         return false;
     }

     return true;
  }
```

And add below code to call JavaScript function to accept only numbers.

```
<%= f.text_field :zip, :onkeypress=> "return isNumberKey(event)"%>
```

Comment: I am still able to type `-` character

Answer (score 1):

You could regex on format :

`validates :answer_no, :format => { :with => /^\d+\.?\d*$/ }`

test on <kbd>**[rubular](http://rubular.com/r/PW286jkZIt)**</kbd>

If you want to define the question type in the method in model, You can write custom validation function :

```
  class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_question_type

   protected
   def check_question_type
     if question_type == ....
       validates :answer_no, :format => { :with => /^\d+\.?\d*$/ }
     else
       validates :answer_no,
         :presence => true      
     end
   end
  end
```

Comment: shall I use like `validates :answer_no, :format => { :with => /^\d+??(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/ }, :if => :answer_cannot_be_string`  and define the question type in the method in model??

Comment: This is awkward. I thought `0.001` was a number but you're telling me it isn't?

Comment: @Gareth because regex `^\d+??(?:\.\d{0,2})?$` is allow maximum of two digits after decimal point. `{0,2}`